# How do I create a flutter project despite the error "At least one platform must be selected"?

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, installation

I'm trying to create a new Flutter project in IntelliJ and I get the [error "At least one platform must be selected"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl8XQ.png)

I followed the instructions from the Flutter website: ( [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive) and [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor)) However when I click on 'Finish' I receive the error shown and in the specified place just an empty folder is created.

### Example from start to end:

- Install the Flutter and Dart plugins from the IntelliJ marketplace
- Click on "Create New Project" and choose Flutter from the list on the left
- Flutter SDK path is prefilled to `/home/nikko/snap/flutter/common/flutter` (see note on flutter), so I click Next
- set name: `tryseven`, location: `~/Folders/Me/Programming/Mobile/Flutter/tryseven`,

  - type: `Application`,
  - organization: `com.example`
  - android language: `Java`
  - iOS language: `Swift`
  - create project offline: False
- the "More settings" tab wasn't changed, default project format is `.idea (directory based)`
- Click finish and I get [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl8XQ.png). When I go to `~/Folders/Me/Programming/Mobile/Flutter/tryseven` the directory is created and is empty

#### Notes:

`flutter --version` returns

```
Flutter 1.22.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 9b2d32b605 (11 days ago) • 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
Engine • revision 2f0af37152
Tools • Dart 2.10.5
```

and if I change the "Flutter SDK path" to something else I get the warning "Flutter SDK is not found in the specified location." So Flutter should be set correctly

---

using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS 64-bit

and IntelliJ IDEA v.2020.1.4

IntelliJ doesn't open after I close it, I need to kill the process first, even though the window is closed. Not sure if that impacts in any way, but I'll reinstall the IDE

---

What I've tried without success:

- changing the language to Kotlin or C
- changing the organization to `test.org`
- changing the type to Package (language and organization selection are disabled)
- changing "Create project offline" to True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the temporary solution create project with cmd

```
flutter create my_app
```

must have flutter environment set in your OS. Then open with intellij project by browse my_app directory.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually allows me to create a project. 

It's not through the plugin which makes it more difficult to use, but it works

Answer (score 4):

Known issue (caused by [flutter/devtools#2653](https://github.com/flutter/devtools/issues/2653)), please see https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5230#issuecomment-771279236 for a workaround

Comment: Hello lena, after removing the new version and putting 52.2.5 I get the error "Incompatible (since build 203.5981.155 > IU-201.8743.12)" and I no longer have the option to create a Flutter project in the menu

Answer (score 4):

Problem is with 53.0 version of Flutter plugin for IntelliJ. You need to install previous version.

1. **Download Flutter plugin** from this link (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?rel=true&updateId=107561)
2. Open **IntelliJ**
3. Go to **Settings**
4. Click on **Plugins**
5. Click on **Settings icon** at the right corner of navbar
6. Click **"Install Plugin from Disk..."**
7. Select **.zip file** of Flutter plugin you just downloaded
8. Restart **IDE**

This works for me, hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using? When I follow these steps exactly I get the error "Plugin 'Flutter' is incompatible with this installation"

Comment: I use IntelliJ Ultimate, and plugin I posted is compatible with that version. Click here (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/versions ) and download plugin for Community version (you have to choose version 52.2.3 or 52.2.5).

Comment: I am also using IntelliJ Ultimate - 
IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.4 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-201.8743.12, built on July 21, 2020
Non-Bundled Plugins: CheckStyle-IDEA, app.teamhub, Dart
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME

Answer (score 0):

I am really sorry for adding another answer but I don't have enough reputation to comment. I tried the solution given by Ben, but it didn't work (partially). The issue originated in an earlier version and a recent update (53.0) brought it back. I installed the 52.2.5 version which worked for me [click here to download version 52.2.5](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?rel=true&updateId=107560) or [pick one which might work for you](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/versions)